# Match Strings Composed of Substrings in a Given Set

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

By searching a dictionary of words, I am trying find strings made up of substrings.

First, finding string made of letters is straight forward:
1. `[abcdefgjlmnqrsz]+`

Above finds any word or phrase that contains the above letters. What I am trying to figure out how to find strings made up of substrings:

So for example `dictionary = ["neon","none","dog","bear","bare"]`

and regex is: `[ar|be|o|ne|n]+`

I would like to find: `neon, bear`

But, regex ex. 2 is incorrect, because it finds: `neon, noen, bear, bare.`

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A Character Class Matches One Single Character

You are looking for

```
\b(?:ar|be|o|ne|n)+\b
```

Note that `[things]` is a character class that matches one single character. Therefore `[ar|be|o|ne|n]` does not mean what you thought: it means "one character that is either one of `a,r,|,b,e,|,o,|,n,e,|,n`

**Explanation**

- `\b` is a word boundary that matches a position where one side is a letter, and the other side is not a letter (for instance a space character, or the beginning of the string)
- `(?: ... )` is a non-capture group
- `|` is the alternation (OR) operator

Comment: ARGH! Thank you. Answer was so simple.

Comment: Yes, I just did. I was trying as soon as you posted, but kept getting a modal: "you must wait X minutes before you can accept this answer". Thanks again.